# How to build a selectSingleBox in Flux using the new field form (v9)?

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

Since the TYPO3 extension Flux (version 9) has marked the usage of its viewhelpers like

```
<flux:field.select name="settings.position"
                items="{
                       0:{0:'On the left side',1:'left'},
                       1:{0:'On the right side',1:'right'}
                       }"
/>
```

as deprecated, I was wondering: How do you build a select-field of renderType 'selectSingleBox' (TCA described here: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/9.5/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/selectSingleBox.html) using the more general flux:field viewhelper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I got:

```
<flux:field name="offerCategory" label="Reiseart" type="select" config=
        "{
         renderType: 'selectCheckBox',
         items: 
           '{
              0:{0:\'Eigenanreise\',1:\'Eigenanreise\'},
              1:{0:\'On the right side\',1:\'right\'}
            }'
         }" 
/>
```

I tried to use the example from official TCA documentation v9.5 (https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/9.5/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/selectSingleBox.html#example) but using brackets and single or double quotes did not work. So I tried to adapt the example of the deprecated flux:field.select (https://viewhelpers.fluidtypo3.org/fluidtypo3/flux/9.0.1/Field/Select.html) and escaped the single quotes.

If you find a solution working with the offical TCA documentation, please let me know.